# Getting null for form parameter after being forwarded or redirected

Tags: java, http, jsp, servlets

I have a very simple log-in servlet with the following code:

```
            userName = request.getParameter("username");
    password = request.getParameter("password");

    if ("xxx".equals(userName) && "xxx".equals(password)) {
        RequestDispatcher requestDisSecure = request
                .getRequestDispatcher("VendorList_Secure.jsp");
        requestDisSecure.forward(request, response);
    }
    if ("xxx".equals(userName) && "xxx".equals(password)) {
        RequestDispatcher requestDisSecure = request
                .getRequestDispatcher("VendorList_Secure.jsp");
        requestDisSecure.forward(request, response);
    }
    if ("xxx".equals(userName) && "xxx".equals(password)) {
        RequestDispatcher requestDisSecure = request
                .getRequestDispatcher("VendorList_Secure.jsp");
        requestDisSecure.forward(request, response);
    }
    if ("xxx".equals(userName) && "xxx".equals(password)) {
        RequestDispatcher requestDisSecure = request
                .getRequestDispatcher("VendorList_Secure.jsp");
        requestDisSecure.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        /**
         * Unauthenticated user
         */
        RequestDispatcher requestDisUnSecure = request
                .getRequestDispatcher("VendorLoginError.jsp");
        requestDisUnSecure.forward(request, response);
    }
```

We come to this servlet logic from VendorLogin.jsp that has username & password parameter, if the login is correct it forward fine to the VendorList_Secure.jsp, but if not it will forward to VendorLoginError.jsp, but after inputting a new username & password and hitting the above servlet, i got both  username & password parameters as null instead of the new updated values in the servlet!

I tried redirect instead, but i got the same effect

I know i could do much better with how to implement login through securing the resources in web.xml, but i want to know why this simple example doesn't work

So what i am doing wrong here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form elements should match the names given in getParameter.

```
userName = request.getParameter("username");
password = request.getParameter("password");
```

that is like below

```
<input type="text" name="username"  />
<input type="password" name="password"  />
```

Comment: there are the same, and i am getting to VendorList_Secure.jsp on my first request to the servlet with the correct credentials. But the problem after sending a wrong username & passwords and being forwarded to VendorLoginError.jsp, I am not getting the new updated values, i am getting only null

Comment: Solved i forget to put the name attribute in the VendorLoginError.jsp, what a stupid mistake ;)

Comment: it happens sometime cooooooooool

Answer (score 0):

Your login jsp should have elements with username and password as there name.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="txtUserName" />
```